# Where to find throttled events of Logic App in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics

I wanted to monitor Azure Logic Apps with the help of Azure Monitor alerts. In alerts, I came across a metric `Run Throttled events` which is showing some numbers in recent days. But I couldn't find any events anywhere to resolve the issue. Is it possible view the actual run throttled events in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup diagnostic logging for Logic Apps, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics).

When you are done with the setup and initial run through of logs and if interested you want to look at more advanced queries via this logs data then go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-monitoring-tracking-queries).

Specifically on throttling you need to see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-throttling-problems-429-errors). Also take a look at limits set for Logic Apps from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config) as well.

Comment: Is it possible to see the exact events with reason for run throttling by configuring Log Analytics? @Hassan Raza

Comment: Throttle usually happens at the app you are calling and not in Logic Apps itself, so if that endpoint you are calling within the Logic App itself is not giving an error then have to go through docs for that service or go through errors received by Log Analytics from that specific log if that endpoint is exposing the reason or maybe an error code which you can then google.